# How to avoid re-rendering while loading data from a REST api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to load initial data inside a component based on an external variable. So I have this:

```
const { dossierId } = useParams();
const { loadDossierData } = useDossierContext();

useEffect(() => {
  loadDossierData(dossierId);
}, [dossierId]);
```

So my application is receiving in the url a parameter called `dossierId`. This parameter is used to load some initial data that must be stored in an accessible for all context.

The context looks like this:

```
  const [dossier, setDossier] = useState({});
  const { get } = useRestServices();

  const loadDossierData = async (dossierId) => {
    const result = await get('myurl/%/dossier', [dossierId]); // This 'get' wrapper just substitutes every % in the url by the items in the following array in the function
    setDossier(result);
    console.log('loadDossierData');
    console.log(result);
  };

  return (
    <DossierContext.Provider
      value={{
        dossier,
        loadDossierData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DossierContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useDossierContext = () => useCustomContext(DossierContext);

export default DossierProvider;
```

So this looks like a normal code:

1. The application loads with an initial dossierId
2. A call to `loadDossierData` is done with that new dossierId
3. A `REST` call is made and data is loaded from backend
4. The context state updates and the updated `dossier` variable is visible for everyone who wants to use it

This is the ideal flow, and I can see it working correct because of the forced `console.log`:

[image]

Nice, no?

But the real problem comes here. In the initial call to the function, where I try to detect any `dossierId` change, the useEffect is warning me about a missing dependency:

[image]

But if I add it to the dependency array, my application runs in an infinite loop:

[image]

I'm trying to improve the way this information is `get` and `stored` in a shared context, but I keep fighting with this re-render thing and I didn't find a solution yet.

Any idea on how to avoid this? I know why the re-render is happening, but I need this flow and I'm not sure on how to do it and avoid re-renders.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `useCallback` to prevent `loadDossierData` from re-rendering.

```
  const loadDossierData = useCallback(async (dossierId) => {
    const result = await get('myurl/%/dossier', [dossierId]); // This 'get' wrapper just substitutes every % in the url by the items in the following array in the function
    setDossier(result);
    console.log('loadDossierData');
    console.log(result);
  }, [setDossier]);
```

Comment: Is using useCallback the correct approach? I'm trying to remove any memoized function or variable if not needed... is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: It is the correct approach, whenever you run `setDossier` it triggers a re-render of the component where `loadDossierData` is defined. This means that it will re-define the `loadDossierData` function into a new reference. Using `useCallback` will prevent that from happening.

Comment: Ok, did it like that and it worked, so I consider this issue fixed. But I'm still struggling on a different way to update my context...